# Determining membership to a left-closed and right-open interval

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have the set $[0,0)$. Would it be correct to say that this set contains $0$? My intuition is that the matter is indeterminate, since we are told that the set both contains, as well as excludes, $0$.

Thank you.

Comment: This is the empty set.  It consists of those real numbers $x$ such that $0≤x<0$ and there are no such $x$.

Comment: It does not say that the set includes $0$. It says that the set contains elements that satisfy $0\leq x<0$. We do have $0\leq0$ but not $0<0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $a,b\in\Bbb R$, then $[a,b)=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid a\leqslant x<b\}$. Therefore,$$[0,0)=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid0\leqslant x<0\}=\emptyset.$$There is nothing indeterminate about this.